# How to send modified bytes through a Dart socket?

Tags: sockets, dart, byte, codepages

I have a data as shown below.

```
List<int> bytes: [231, 199, 287, 286, 305, 304, 351, 350, 246, 214, 252, 220, 13, 10];
```

I believe  I have to use **socket.add(bytes)**; But I am not sure if this is the correct way.

Main goal is to send none encoded string to server and it seems I can do it via sending as bytes.

Above bytes will be replace to **IBM CP850** codepage (byte).

**Example:** [231] will be replace to [167]. And I have no problem with this.

Also documentation stated that I need to use flush and done to get any errors if generated  by this call.

Does anyone know good example for this?

**Note:** For string I use below code. But I need to modified code to send bytes to socket.

```
 _socket = await Socket.connect('192.168.22.120', 3000);
  _socket.handleError((data) {
    _secureResponse = "$_errorData}";
  });

  await for (var data in _socket) {
    _reply = new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();

    int dataLen;
    dataLen = _reply.length;

    int carriageReturnPosition;
    carriageReturnPosition = dataLen - 2;

    int newLinePosition;
    newLinePosition = dataLen - 1;

    if (_reply.substring(carriageReturnPosition, newLinePosition) == '\r' &&
        _reply.substring(newLinePosition, dataLen) == '\n') {
      _socket.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you question are. Can you provide a example or some pseudocode where you show what you want. As I understand you code you are not actually sending any data but are instead receiving.

Comment: Julemand101, my nor al sending data code was above await for loop as simply put an socket.write("fgftvgg"); But I need to send byte like List<int> _byteData = [167, 158 .......]. And I dont know how to send. I cannot use socket.write because some encoding issue on server. Example if I want to send İ ( upper i with dot above) my byte representation (dart) is [304] and the server representaion of same character is [152].

Comment: Ok, but did you call socket.flush() before socket.close()? Note that flush() returns a future you need to await before calling close().

Comment: The server terminates the that connection when it receives the [... 13, 10] end of the byte array. So I assuming its safe for me to use close. Same thing in my side. when I receive the data and end of the data has '\r' and '\n' I close the connection. But my question is how to send byte array to socket? socket.write(byte) not working...

Comment: Thats because you need to call writeAll since you input are a List.

Comment: does writeAll(byes) enough? What is the differences between socket.add?

Comment: Well, after some thoughts I think add() are properly more correct (since it takes a List<int> as input). But please remember to use flush() and close() after using add() since the call are non-blocking. Don't assume you can just use close() since there are no guarantee that all data has been sent.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.